# how to once fetched data in different 2 div?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want to show fetched data in 2 differnt div. I had fetched 2 random data from database, to show in two div. My 1st div had leftside content and right side image and 2nd div had leftside image and rightside content. So how can i show fetched data in 2 different div.

Below i provide my divs

```
<div class="new-product">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia sint minima, ab asperiores dolores, aspernatur tempora veritatis consectetur omnis ea dolor, doloremque impedit assumenda placeat quod eligendi! Error, quos, quidem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia sint minima, ab asperiores dolores, aspernatur tempora veritatis consectetur omnis ea dolor, doloremque impedit assumenda placeat quod eligendi! Error, quos, quidem.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is fetch data query

```
$result  = $this->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM wm_products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            }
        }
```

below is output-
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do it like this:

```
$result  = $this->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM wm_products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");

$i = 0;
$html = "";
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $html .= "<div class='new-product'>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($i%2 == 0) {
            $html .= "<div class='row'>
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <p>{$row->text}</p>
                </div>
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <img src='{$row->image}' alt=''>
                </div>
            </div>";
        } else {
            $html .= "<div class='row'>   
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <img src='{$row->image}' alt=''>
                </div>
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <p>{$row->text}</p>
                </div>
           </div>";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $html .= "</div>";
}

echo $html;
```

Assuming that your columns in SQL query are named as `text` and `image`. Otherwise replace the `$row->text` and `$row->image` with respective column names.

Comment: i want show div at a time. it's not work in if else statement

Comment: Could you share a bit more details, please? Your original question states that you want to display data in 2 divs and so would suggest the HTML example you shared.

Comment: In addition to the above (sorry, can't do edits any more), I have updated my answer. Please have a look if that's better now.

Comment: i provide output in image in quetion check it.

Comment: Thanks, is it a result of my code, or just your example? And if it's result of my code, how would you like it to look?